# Finding matching dates for same user across two tables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two lists, each of which contains a list of time frames for various users. I want to identify places where a start date for a specific user in one list is the same (or within 1 day, if possible, but I'll settle for an exact match) as the user's stop date in the other list, or vice versa.

List 1

```
User        Start       Stop
User1       1/1/2014    3/15/2014
User1       6/1/2014    12/1/2015
User2       3/1/1998    9/2/2016
User3       4/10/2007   3/5/2011
User3       9/6/2013    9/8/2013
User3       5/20/2014   5/25/2014
```

List 2

```
 User      Start        Stop
 User1     3/15/2014    5/31/2014
 User1     12/5/2014    2/10/2016
 User1     8/2/2016     1/1/2017
 User2     5/15/2010    6/25/2010
 User2     2/1/2012     3/1/2012
 User3     6/1/2012     9/5/2013
 User3     4/25/2014    2/8/2017
```

In the above example:

- the Stop date in the first entry for User1 is the same as the Start date in the first entry for User1 in List 2. There are no other matching dates, so I would only want to highlight that occurrence.
- For User2, List 1 shows one big long time frame. Even though List 2 has two time frames that are completely within the List 1 time frame, the start/stop dates are not the same, so they are not meaningful.
- For User 3, the Start date in the first entry in List 1 is the day after the Stop date in first entry for User 3 in List 2. So I would like to highlight this somehow. The other time frames are not associated in anyway, so they are not meaningful.

Can anyone help me find my matches? I have thousands of rows. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are screenshots showing where I am -

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check only exact matches, easiest way is probably to use `COUNTIFS`:
`=OR(COUNTIFS(List2[User],[@User],List2[Start],[@Stop]),COUNTIFS(List2[User],[@User],List2[Stop],[@Start]))`

Looking for 1 day differences too, you need to use `SUMPRODUCT`:
`=OR(SUMPRODUCT((List2[User]=[@User])*(ABS(List2[Start]-[@Stop])<=1)),SUMPRODUCT((List2[User]=[@User])*(ABS(List2[Stop]-[@Start])<=1)))`

In the example below I've added calculation in a new column to list1, you can add it to both lists and filter for matches.

[image]

You can see the calculation step by step by going to formulas tab - "evaluate formula"

Comment: I'm getting an error with both formulas. I am supposed to create a group, right? Also, my actual values differ in that instead of User it's actually an account number. Perhaps that's throwing it off? Thank you for your help. EDIT: Are you using two different sheets?

Comment: `List1` and `List2` are tables (insert tab - table). In formulas tan - name manager you can change the names.  It doesn't matter whether they're on the same sheet.

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. But now it's saying all false when I know that some of them are true. Also performed the calculation instantly on all of them really quickly, when I think it should take longer. EDIT: Now it works - my dates were more specific than I realized, had to convert to text. Still having issues with the SUMPRODUCT. It's saying #VALUE. Thanks again

Comment: It shouldn't take long:) please post screenshot how exactly you set up your calculation.

Comment: I posted photos above, Table 1 is linked

Comment: I don't know how else to troubleshoot. I have to mask the User values, because they're user IDs. They're just multidigit numbers, and they're working for the other formula. And yes, it is working on my data above.

Comment: got it - it wasn't working before because I'd converted the date columns to actual dates. Needed to cut and paste to text editor, then paste in as a general or unspecified column type